# Cell width control in tabularx environment

Tags: tables, tabularx

The MWE generates the table, however, I'm intended to do following
I tried to add text in 3rd and 4th column but if I add text in 3rd column it also increases the size of cells in the 2nd column, can someone guide me how to encounter the problem.

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{A  model}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{12mm}|>{\hsize=0.9\hsize}X|
                                      >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|
                                      >{\hsize=0.9\hsize}X|}
    \hline
\thead{Ref. no(s)}  & \thead{Used} & \thead{adjective} &   \thead{yield} \\
    \hline
\cite{9}            
                    &Reduces the required computational cost 

                        & \multirow{5}{=}{This pricing scheme refers to a list of price plans for different products or services, which come along with differentiated
quantities or qualities [17]. It can ensure that the pricing entity
(LSE in this paper) can lead the formulation of price, while
providing consumers with more flexible price plans. As shown
in Fig. 2, the main procedure includes:
1) LSE notifies the required load adjustment signals.
2) The i-th CL voluntarily provides information at time t
including price bids (price asked for) θ+
di,t
, θ−
di,t
, upper bounds
of load adjustment P¯ +
di,t
, P¯ −
di,t and elasticity coefficient εdi.
Here + denotes load increase, − denotes load decrease. The
load adjustment at time t is related to not only the price at
time t, but also the price at other times [18]. The elasticity coefficient εdi is a vector including the self-elasticity and
cross-elasticity, i.e.,}  &Research and development in flywheel, compressed air, thermal (molten salts), and hydrogen storage systems are making great progress. In addition to physical storage devices, great potential lies in the exploitation of end-use side energy storage for the grid. For example, energy-demand management of water heaters and air-conditioning cycling utilizes the thermal energy stored in water tanks and buildings at consumer premises in exchange for electricity. Smart vehicle charging and discharging (or vehicle-to-grid, V2G) technology utilizes electrochemical energy stored in the batteries of EVs/PHEVs to act as energy storage for the grid. These “virtual energy-storage systems,” when properly managed in the future grid, can provide a large quantity of cost-efficient power in both directions to the grid.   \\
 \cline{1-2}
\cite{03}           & Minimizes the computational cost and time period
                         &   &   \\
\cline{1-2}
 \cite{14,15}       & Achieving least value to scale up the solution
                        &   &   \\
\hline
Designed model      &  In this paper, a relatively new yet superior clustering algorithm based on density peak, proposed by Rodriguez and Laio,
is introduced and employed & \multirow{5}{=}{According to the clustering features of the CLs’ historical information, LSE can divide CLs into K+ types of load
increase and K− types of load decrease. Moreover, when the
market for DR participants is immature, not all of consumers
will bid voluntarily. In that case, LSE has to forecast the cost
function of load adjustment of consumers based on the historical data. Alternatively, the cost function could be reflected
by other market signals such as reserve service (or frequency
regulation) prices or value of customer reliability.
3)}  &  From Smart Grid to Internet of Energy covers novel and emerging metering and monitoring technologies, communication systems, and technologies in smart grid areas to present a valuable reference for readers from various engineering backgrounds. Considering relevant topics on the essentials of smart grids and emerging wireless communication systems, such as IEEE 802.15.4 based novel technologies, cognitive radio networks and Internet of Energy, this book offers a discussion on the emerging trends and research direction for communication technologies. The book includes research concepts and visualization of smart grids and related communication technologies, making it a useful book for practicing network engineers. \\   \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGikt.png
```

Comment: Off-topic: In a two-column document setup, the only place where LaTeX will place a `table*` (or `figure*`) environment is at the top of a page. The `[!t]` placement option is redundant.

Comment: Also, how do you expect LaTeX to hyphenate and line-break the string `dajkfhdkafhdfhakfhdkfhdafhdkafhdkafhakfh`? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico,  I removed the [!t] as you said.  Even I understood what you said in the second comment.  Still, my points 1 and 2 remain unanswered.

Comment: To break text in `multirow` cell you need to define its width. IN your case `\multirow{<number of lines>}{=}{ cell content}` (see documentation for `multirow` package). Your text in `multirow` cell span about 15 to 20 lines of text (depend on font size), consequently spill out of bottom of table. You need to provide more information about your document/table. Does real text in the second column maybe have more than one line?

Comment: @Zarko, Thanks for response. Yes 2nd column text is more than one line, and I tried to use multirow with a different width but it didn't work, can you do that using the above code.

Comment: Please can you provide dummy example for text in the second column?

Comment: Sure! here is the text to use in second column but I will use it 3rd row "Thirdly, based on the information provided by consumers
and ISO, LSE will make decisions regarding electricity procurement, power output of distributed generation, and compensation price. It is worth mentioning that consumers’ response
to the compensation price is different, because their marginal
cost of load adjustment (i.e., the incremental cost on increasing or reducing one unit of load power) is usually not the
same. Therefore, different categories of compensation prices
should be provided."

Answer (score 1):

- To achieve automatic break of text in the `multirow` cell you must define width of the `multirow` cell. In you case, you can overtake width of the column defined with `X` column specifier:

```
\multirow{12}{=}{...}
```

- Your real table look is still unknown, so the following solution will may not give desired result. In it I assume that in the second column text have in average three lines  per cell:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\thead{\bfseries\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{A  model}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{16mm}|>{\hsize=0.9\hsize}X|
                                      >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|
                                      >{\hsize=0.9\hsize}X|}
    \hline
\thead{Ref. no(s)}  & \thead{Used} & \thead{adjective} &   \thead{yield} \\
    \hline
\cite{9}            
                    & ------------------------------------------
                      ------------------------------------------
                      ------------------------------------------
                        & \multirow{10}{=}{The CLs’ cost function is formulated accordingto reference [16], i.e., bid information is comprised of price,boundary of load adjustment and price elasticity. If the bidsof consumers are not determined by the three parameters usedin this paper, the prices on the plan can still be calculated bythe clustering and classification method in Section IV and thepricing approach in Section V.}
                            &   \\
 \cline{1-2}
\cite{03}           & ------------------------------------------
                      ------------------------------------------
                      ------------------------------------------
                         &   &   \\
\cline{1-2}
 \cite{14,15}       & ------------------------------------------
                      ------------------------------------------
                      ------------------------------------------
                        &   &   \\
\hline
Designed model      &   &   &   \\   \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: When I reduce the text to one line in 2nd column then the text in the third column goes down. Secondly, what I'm expecting is that the  3rd cloumn rows remain the same as in your example, however, the size of 1st and 2nd column rows should be fixed and remain unchanged with 3rd column.

Comment: @Shane, than please make this changes yourself. This should not be so difficult, isn't it? However, you need to guarantee that height of by `multirow` spanned cells is higher than content of `multirow` cell. Anyway, answer solve your problem how to break text in `multirow` cells. For other, you need to provide more complete MWE in you question. You left us on guessing ...

Comment: ! I agreed with you what you said, I tried you code width different ways, but the only problem is "if add more text in 3rd column it also increases the size of cells in the 2nd column", I also edit the question and used all what I can show to you.